# List of all soft deleted resources in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blueprints

I started to work with Azure Blueprints, and to make the usage "repeatable" it is desirable to "clean" automatically all resources they have created in a resource group and re-assign the  blueprint.

As I have experienced, some resource types get only soft-deleted, when I delete a RG.
Can I somehow know,

- which resource types even have a soft-deletion feature (key vaults + APIM + ???)
- list with one powershell command all soft deleted resources in a given subscription or RG ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the **soft-deletion feature property for a particular resource like key Vault**, you can make use of below CLI command:

```bash
az login

az keyvault show --subscription SubID -g ResourceGroupName -n VaultName
```

**Output:**

[image]

Currently we don't have any cmdlet to list all the resource types that support soft delete and also to list the resources which were enabled with soft delete under a particular subscription.

**References:**

[Azure Key Vault recovery overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-recovery?tabs=azure-powershell#what-are-soft-delete-and-purge-protection)

[Azure keyvault soft delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-overview).